# How to aggregate multiple rows from different dataframe in R?

Tags: r, merge, apply, lapply

Suppose, I have 3 dataframe named a, b, c contains observed values and predicted values for 5 fold.

```
> a
  fold observerd predicted
1    1        10        20
2    2        20        30
3    3        30        40
4    4        40        50
5    5        50        60
> b
  fold observerd predicted
1    1        15        25
2    2        25        35
3    3        35        45
4    4        45        55
5    5        55        65
> c
  fold observerd predicted
1    1        16        26
2    2        26        36
3    3        36        46
4    4        46        56
5    5        56        66
```

Now, I want merge the observaed values and predicted values for every fold like the following.

```
> d
  fold observerd predicted
1    1        10        20
2    1        15        25
3    1        16        26
> e
  fold observerd predicted
1    2        20        30
2    2        25        35
3    2        26        36
..etc
```

Here my ultimate goal is to determine various statistical parameters (correlation coeff. R, RMSE etc.) between observed values and predicted values for each fold (i.e. for fold 1, R=1, for fold 2, R=0.98 like this).

In reality, I have total 48 dataframes and each dataframe contains 82 fold. So, How can I do this job by using apply/loop/something like that?

Comment: I would rbind them all together, and then use my split/do/recombine package of choice (data.table, dplyr, etc) to do my calculations per fold.

Comment: In addition, why are all these dataframes separate in your environment? It's probably easier to create them all as one list to start with.

Comment: To make the input data frames into a list  `L <- list(a = a, b = b, c = c)` or if they are the only data frames in your workspace:  `L <- Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls()))` would do it.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation would be to work in a single data.frame. You can then apply any calculations to subsections of that data.frame later. One way is to use the `dplyr` package for that. See here for an example.

## Load in data

```
a <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
fold observerd predicted
1    1        10        20
2    2        20        30
3    3        30        40
4    4        40        50
5    5        50        60')
b <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
fold observerd predicted
1    1        15        25
2    2        25        35
3    3        35        45
4    4        45        55
5    5        55        65')
c <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
fold observerd predicted
1    1        16        26
2    2        26        36
3    3        36        46
4    4        46        56
5    5        56        66')
```

## `dplyr`

#### Combine with `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- bind_rows(a, b, c, .id = 'table')
```

#### Get statistics with `group_by` and `summarize`

```
# For example, calculate the correlation coefficient and the sum of squares per fold.
dat %>%
  group_by(fold) %>%
  summarize(r = cor(observerd, predicted),
            ss = sum((observerd - predicted) ^ 2))
```

`do` allows for some more complicated stuff (like model fitting). See `?do`.

## Base R

If you want to remain in base R, I would still recommend a similar approach.

#### Combine with `rbind`

```
dat2 <- rbind(a, b, c) # no identifier here
```

#### Get statistics with `split` and `sapply`

```
# For example, get the correlation coefficient per fold
spl <- split(dat2, dat2$fold)
sapply(spl, function(d) cor(d$observerd, d$predicted))
```

(I think you misspelled observed.)

Comment: Thanks Axeman. But I have total 48 data frames  with different names. Each contains 82 fold.  In that case if I write `dat2 <- rbind(a, b, c.......)` in this way then it will be lengthy I think. Is there any other way to do this using Base R?

Comment: If those are your only data.frames that you have in your workspace, you can do (as per @G.Grothendieck): `L <- Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls()))`; `dat <- do.call(L, rbind)`.

Comment: But you probably want to use something like `lapply(file.names, read.table)` to get them as a list while reading them in. (I have too little information here.)